# Python PyPresence when connecting TypeError: A Future or Coroutine is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am working on a little program called RPCCLI, source code can be found here: https://github.com/okramardev/rpccli !

The code works fine on Linux, but when I compile it with PyInstaller (Export as Directory not one-file) and run it, it shows me:

```
Connecting to Discord... To end RPC press CTRL-C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 56, in <module>
  File "pypresence\presence.py", line 45 in connect
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 296, in run_until_complete
  File "asyncio\tasks.py", line 516, in async
TypeError: A Future or coroutine is required
[8600] ailed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseClient.handshake' was never awaited
```

I am using pypresence==4.2.1 in C:\Python39\Lib\Site-Packages

And if I run it on Windows without beeing compilied, it works fine.